# How to grab the id for querySelector using react module?

Tags: reactjs

```
<div>
    <label> <b>Date:</b> </label>
    <input className={styles["form-input"]} type="date" name="date" id={styles["date"]} value={date}/>
</div>    

const dateElement = document.querySelector('#');
```

How to grab the id for querySelector?

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't show it in the code in your question, you seem to already have the value that you're asking about in a `styles` object at the property `date` — you use even use it to assign it to the input's `id` attribute in your code:

```jsx
<input {/*...*/} id={styles["date"]} {/*...*/} />
```

That said, the idiomatic way to obtain a reference to an element is to use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), like this:

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.4/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

function App () {
  const dateElementRef = useRef(null); // 1. Create the ref here
  const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState('2022-11-25');

  useEffect(() => {
    // 3. Use the ref to refer to the element in this effect callback function:
    if (dateElementRef.current) {
      console.log('This is the date element:', dateElementRef.current);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <strong>Date:</strong>
        <input
          type="date"
          ref={dateElementRef} // 2. Assign it to the element here
          onChange={ev => setDateValue(ev.target.value)}
          value={dateValue}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

reactRoot.render(<App />);

</script>
```